# How to link to a tabbed section of another page?

Tags: jquery, tabs, hyperlink

I have a webpage and if I click a link in the page, it should be redirected to a particular tab of another url. That is, I have a link called 'Submitted' in my home page. If I click that link, it show display the 'Submitted' tab of the view page. Is this possible?

```
$status="Submitted";
<a id="formStatus<?php echo $status;?>" class="code_link" href="/FormBuilder/main/viewAllMyForms"><?php echo $status;?></a>
```

In my viewAllMyForms page, I have a tab section like

```
<ul id="sort_by" class="horizontal_navigation float_left">
   <span class="showfilter">Show:</span>
        <li> <a id="all"  class="selected" href="#">All</a></li>
        <li> <a id="drafted"  href="#">Drafts</a></li>
        <li> <a id="submitted"  class="last" href="#">Submitted</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my script I have the below code, so that when I click the Submitted tab in my viewAllMyForms page, only the forms with status "Submitted" are displayed.

```
$('#submitted , #formStatusSubmitted').click(function(){

<?php foreach($myForms as $form):
  if($form['Form']['status']=="Incompleted"){ ?>
    $('.fm_myformsample_container'+<?php echo $form['Form']['id'];?>).hide();
<?php }

 else{?>
   $('.fm_myformsample_container'+<?php echo $form['Form']['id'];?>).show();
<?php }
endforeach;?>
$('#sort_by').find(".selected").removeClass();
$('#submitted').addClass("selected");
});
```

So When I click the "submitted" link in the home page, how to connect it to the "Submitted" link in the viewAllMyForms page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect from the first page to secondpage.html#submitted

In JavaScript you check in the $(document).ready() of the secondpage.html if there is a hashtag available thru

```
document.location.hash
```

and if there is '#submitted', you show the submitted part of your page.

Comment: You have given the right answer in the first case and I missed out the # while checking the condition if(document.location.hash=="#submitted") and didn't get the answer. Only now figured out my mistake..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure on what you're asking, but if you want to trigger the click event that you made for your tabs, then you could use jQuery [trigger](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/trigger) with the hash tag, as suggested by Jan:

```
if (location.hash == "submitted") {
    $("#submitted").trigger("click");
}
```

And then set up your link to include a hashtag:

```
<a id="formStatus<?php echo $status;?>" class="code_link" 
   href="/FormBuilder/main/viewAllMyForms#submitted"><?php echo $status;?></a>
```

Comment: I tried this,but I still don't get the answer. I did an alert inside the if(location.hash) block, the alert didn't pop up..

Comment: the `location.hash` might return the string including the actual hashkey. Have you tried just: `alert(location.hash)` to see what the output is?

Comment: Yes I figured this out after a long time. The if condition matches only if I give #submitted. But Jan had suggested it rightly.. Only I didn't notice properly..